# Access function written in php file on another server

Tags: php

I want to access some function written in some php file on another server. I include file by using `file_get_contents`. I set `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` to true. It opens the file. But still I am unable to access functions defined in the included file.

Error i got is:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function contact()

Can anybody guide me how can I do it.

Comment: To do this you'd have to be able to get the *raw PHP code* via an HTTP request. In other words, you'd be able to see PHP code when visiting the given URL in your browser. ... Doesn't sound like a great idea, does it?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use include function

```
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';
```

http://www.php.net/include

Comment: no. it gives error. that's why i used `file_get_contents` function to include php file on another server.

Comment: file_get_contents loads file to variable. Have you set 'allow_url_include' directive in php.ini to 'On'? Also make sure that remote file exists (for example: wget remote_php_url).

Comment: Yes i made all changes but still I am getting same error. That file is exists on the server.

Comment: Check that your remote web server returns valid php code. Something like: <?php function contact() {echo "Hi";}

Comment: No. It does not give any output :(

Comment: I checked code. It opens file but it is not executing function defined in file included from other server

Comment: It's because your remote server returns empty string instead of raw php code.

Comment: Then what should I do for this?

Comment: Copy remote files on local server and include it locally. Or disable php processing on remote server and return php files as text files. BTW, second variant is totally unsecure.

Comment: I can't do it. Because I am access database from web server. If I include it locally it gives error as: _host name is incorrect_